# How to match pattern after first 32 letters using the grep?

Tags: awk, grep

I was trying to filter lines with pattern 04:26. I expected the command,

```
cat file1.txt | grep -E '04:26'
```

to filter the lines which contain 04:26 after timestamps. Instead, I got the second line also.

file1.txt

```
2022-12-23T04:26:47.748412+00:00 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:04:26 
2022-12-23T04:26:47.749307+00:00 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:34:13
```

How to mask the first 32 letters of timestamps from matching?

Comment: if `grep '04:26$' file` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 5):

You may use this `grep`:

```bash
grep -E '^.{32,}04:26' file

2022-12-23T04:26:47.748412+00:00 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:04:26
```

**Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `.{32,}`: Match 32 or more characters
- `04:26`: Match `04:26`

---

Alternatively you can use this `grep` as well:

```bash
grep ' .*04:26' file
```

Considering the fact that you want to ignore timestamp text that is before first space in each line.

---

An `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '$NF ~ /04:26/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator to 32 characters from starting of line, then in main program checking if 2nd field is matching everything till `:` followed by `04:26` if this condition matches then print that line.

```bash
awk -F'^.{32}' '$2~/^.*:04:26/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` checking that there are 2 or more fields as the value that you don't want to match is in the first field.

```
awk 'NF > 1 && $NF ~ /04:26/' file
```

Or with `awk` checking that the line has more than 37 characters and match 04:26 in last field.

```
awk 'length($0) > 37 && index($NF, "04:26")' file
```

Or `grep` matching 32 or more characters and then match 04:26

```
grep -E '^.{32,}04:26' file
```

Output

```
2022-12-23T04:26:47.748412+00:00 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:04:26
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many simple ways you can do this, trying to avoid side cases. The cleanest way would be the programmatical way in which you identify what you try to search for. The robust way would be `awk` but you can do it also with `grep` pipe-lines:

**grep for MAC-address:**

```
$ grep -E '([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}' file
$ awk '/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/' file
```

**grep for MAC-address that *ends* with `04:46`:**

```
$ grep -E '([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){4}04:46' file
$ awk '/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){4}04:46/' file
```

**grep for MAC-address in last field that *ends* with `04:46`:**

```
$ grep -E '([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){4}04:46[[:blank:]]*$' file
$ awk '$NF~/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){4}04:46/' file
```

**grep for MAC-address that *contains* with `04:46`:**

```
$ grep -oE '([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}' file | grep '04:46' | grep -Ff - file
$ awk 'match($0,/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)~/04:46/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to mask first 32 letters

You might use [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to get 33th and following character in each line, let `file1.txt` content be

```
2022-12-23T04:26:47.748412+00:00 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:04:26 
2022-12-23T04:26:47.749307+00:00 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:34:13
```

then

```
cut --characters=33- file.txt
```

gives output

```
 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:04:26 
 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:34:13
```

which could then by fused with your code as follows

```
cut --characters=33- file.txt | grep -E '04:26'
```

that result in output output

```
 raspberrypi dnsmasq-dhcp[698]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.42.17 04:c8:07:23:04:26
```

Explanation: `--characters=` is used to select certain characters from each line, `33-` means 33th character and following.

*(tested in GNU grep 3.4)*